# Why is the user input not being inserted to my .txt document?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to take user input using batch files and insert that user input into a .txt document in my school's pupil shared folder that can be accessed by all pupils the .txt document is then printed onto the screen and you are prompted to add more text. This is what should happen but the user input is currently not being saved to the .txt document.

here is the code

```
cls
type cblog.txt
echo.
set /p text=
%text% >> cblog.txt
```

Comment: ECHO %text% >> cblog.txt

Comment: Also, instead of `if %pass% equ 2730 goto enter` it should read `If Not "%pass%"=="2730" GoTo start`

Comment: And it would be definitely better to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). On using `echo %text% >> cblog.txt` and the user enters `I corrupt now my machine ... & rd C:\Users /S /Q` the last part `rd C:\Users /S /Q` would be executed as command and not as text to write to handle __STDOUT__ with redirection into the text file `cblog.txt`.

Comment: Thank you that is exactally what i was needing